# PNG images not showing on Safari and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, image, safari, png

I've got a problem with PNG images not showing up on Safari and iOS.
They're working fine on Chrome, but when I open the page on Safari, or Safari/Chrome on iPhone, the PNG images are not showing up.

The inspector says that the image couldn't be loaded due to closed connection by the server.

It's worth mentioning that all the other image types, such as JPG or SVG work fine on all browsers, and it's just the pngs that are affected by this issue.

Any idea what could be the problem?

The website in question: https://typitap.com

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turned out I had an outdated version of echo framework (for Golang). After upading it, the png images are showing up just fine.